# rubyonrails error when update to gem 1.8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I update gem to the latest 1.8.1
and now when i use rails command
i got errors as below

```
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. 
It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/rubygems-update-1.7.2.gemspec:11.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Haxrat/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/RedCloth-4.2.7.gemspec:10.
```

Comment: Are these actually errors (preventing rails from running), or just warnings?

Comment: just warning ,rails functions as normal

Comment: ive ran into the same problem, for a temporary fix revert to an older version of rubygems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just deprecation warnings. Lots of stuff in rubygems is deprecated in this version, read http://blog.zenspider.com/2011/05/rubygems-18-is-coming.html for more details.

Answer (score 8):

Gem 1.8 adds lots of deprecation warnings, see http://blog.zenspider.com/2011/05/rubygems-18-is-coming.html

> Most noise coming from the specs
>   themselves can be cleaned up very very
>   easily with gem pristine:
>
> gem pristine --all --no-extensions

You could also directly edit the .gemspecs that are noisy and remove the old methods (e.g. in your case, remove line 11 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/rubygems-update-1.7.2.gemspec)

Comment: I just made a bug report for this over-the-top "warning": https://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=29176&group_id=126&atid=575

You may want to leave a supportive comment there or in Ryan's blog post if you feel (as I do) that the "gem" command is the user interface to the entire world of Ruby development,
for people of all experience levels, and has a special responsibility not to be scary, especially about things the user can't do anything about.

Comment: Update: an easier fix, at least for the time being, is to use RubyGems version 1.7.2 instead of 1.8.1.

    `gem update --system 1.7.2`

and the "NOTE" garbage should disappear.