# 1.8.1 gem rollback to 1.7.2 and still get some deprecation warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

OK, so i updated to gem version 1.8.1 and got this problem where it would have too many deprecation warnings so i rolled back to version 1.7.2 and also ran `gem pristine --all --no-extensions` following what [rubyonrails error when update to gem 1.8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915338/rubyonrails-error-when-update-to-gem-1-8-1), said to do, but now i still have the some warnings here and there(rake commands and some gems).

I ran rake db:migrate and i get this:

```
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#all_gems is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#all_gems called from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/rubygems_
integration.rb:256
```

I tried running `gem pristine --all --no-extensions` again but it gives me *invalid option: --no-extensions*

Any ideas how to get rid of this little nuisance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bundler 1.0.13** (version released May 4, 2011) running with **rubygems 1.7.2** issues this annoying deprecation warning:

> NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#all_gems is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
> Gem::SourceIndex#all_gems called from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@composer/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:256

A [fix was committed](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/commit/9ad9d000d6427494dae21a67dd8e841985564d06) on 5/11/2011 in the Bundler repo [to correct an issue](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1151) submitted 5/6/2011.

Pending release of Bundler 1.1, you can try this solution:

> $ gem uninstall bundler
>
> $ gem install bundler --version=1.0.12

I hope this helps. Took some digging to find it.

Comment: Ah sweet, finally, Thanks a million!

Comment: Bundler 1.0.14 is out and addresses this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check here: [How to avoid deprecation messages from RubyGems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909108/how-to-avoid-deprecation-messages-from-rubygems) Seems that sticking with the older version of rubygems might be the easiest way to go.