# Rails printing out a bunch of unnecessary stuff

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

When I do any command with rails or rake, it prints out tons of deprecation warning every single time. I am simply learning rails with the agile book... I do not need to wade through all this constantly.

Here is the output of "rake test". Please, can somebody tell me what this is and how to stop it?

raben-brodies-macbook:depot Ben$ rake test
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/erubis-2.6.6.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rack-1.2.2.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/treetop-1.4.9.gemspec:11.
(in /Users/Ben/Documents/Programming/agile_web_projects/depot)
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/erubis-2.6.6.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rack-1.2.2.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/treetop-1.4.9.gemspec:11.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/erubis-2.6.6.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rack-1.2.2.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/treetop-1.4.9.gemspec:11.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/erubis-2.6.6.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rack-1.2.2.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/treetop-1.4.9.gemspec:11.
Loaded suite /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
.
Finished in 0.031176 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/erubis-2.6.6.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rack-1.2.2.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/treetop-1.4.9.gemspec:11.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/erubis-2.6.6.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rack-1.2.2.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/treetop-1.4.9.gemspec:11.
Loaded suite /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
.......
Finished in 0.231249 seconds.

7 tests, 10 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/erubis-2.6.6.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rack-1.2.2.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/treetop-1.4.9.gemspec:11.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/erubis-2.6.6.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rack-1.2.2.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/treetop-1.4.9.gemspec:11.
ben-brodies-macbook:depot Ben$

Comment: possible duplicate of [rubyonrails error when update to gem 1.8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915338/rubyonrails-error-when-update-to-gem-1-8-1)

Answer (score 1):

It's a duplicate as the commenter (spender) said, but the simplest thing is to revert your rubygems to a less frustrating version until the dust settles

gem update --system 1.7.2 (or 1.6.2 even)